# problem in the textblock style

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

Hello I am trying to make a textblock that they should focus on the event to underline the text and add when you lose the focus off him.
this is possible?

Comment: This question is not very clear, can you try restating it?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure if this is supported in Silverlight, this is how you'd do it in WPF:

```
<xxx.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="HoverUnderline" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
...
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HoverUnderline}"
           Content="Point at me to underline."/>
```

(Another interpretation of your question: use `IsFocused` instead of `IsMouseOver`.  That's a weirder interpretation though since normally text blocks can't receive focus.)